# Codeception warning instead of failed

Tags: testing, codeception

Is there a way to make a assertion not as error and only as warning. That a build is green but you get some infos.

Answer (score 0):

There is `$I->comment();` which just writes a line into the console.

You could also write your own Command like [this](https://gist.github.com/sd-tm/37d5f9bca871c72648cb).

Comment: No, the question is not to output a info. It is to say that a assertion will only prompt an warning and not an error. Like in a code standard.